# Knowledge Level Assessment Feature for Stack Overflow

Tags: feature-request

As of right now, the only way to tell users apart is rating, answers per day and medals collected, which makes it somewhat difficult to determine how experienced some users are. 
Can some kind of testing feature be implemented that will allow people to take a couple tests and then get either a certificate or a title? Users will be able to decide if they want to display their certs/titles in their profile.

**Benefits:**

- Will allow users to search for hard/easy questions... easier to filter
- Will indicate how familiar a user is with the topic
- Will help new users get acclimated faster
- Can be used for something like 'Report as bad answer. Not correct. Force user to pass cert/test before allowing him/her to post on this topic again.'
- fun!

**Disadvantages:**

- Lots of people will call each other stupid, and will be a lot more inclined to downvote answers that are made by people without certs.
- people will be able to just google for answers... and mods will have to force re-evaluations... and lots of mess all around will be created that nobody wants to deal with.

Comment: Can we pick our own title if we pass the test? I've got a few ideas for mine...

Comment: But seriously, who is going to make these assessment tests for **all** of the different topics? And who will manage this? I see what you are going for but I just don't think it is a feasible aspect of SO, currently (if ever). Also, some already think users on SO are elitests. I'm sure this will just give them more ammo.

Comment: Don't you think the disadvantages far outweigh the benefits?

Comment: I think that this topic can be worked on... It is not US Senate where everything goes or nothing happens.. Things can be adjusted.

Comment: Answers should be judged on their own merits, not on the score that the person that wrote it got on a test that is likely to be quite unrelated from the topic at hand.

Comment: There is a bunch of tests for each topic, and I am pretty sure that there is at least one mod for each tag... I am sure that there are people who are qualified to create some kind of test for their board

Comment: Are users allowed to use stackoverflow to get answers to those test questions?

Comment: sure, there is nothing wrong with showing answers at the end of the test.

Comment: isnt this already in place?  Bad answer == down votes; The smart person/expert eventually gets rep, language tag badges etc

Comment: @Dimitri There are over 39636 tags and 17 mods.  So no, there is not one mod per tag.

Comment: @Dimitri So this test is merely a test of whether or not you're capable of copy-pasting the question into google and copy-pasting the answer back over?  That's a pretty low bar for your test.

Comment: @Servy might be a good test for ability to do research before posting a question :P

Comment: @eddie_cat Research, at the level expected by Stack Overflow, is not a question of ability, but of willingness.  Also note that this is a test for answering, not asking, as proposed anyway.

Answer (score 2):

### Measuring User Expertise

Stack Overflow already has a system in place that can be used to roughly gauge a user's experience and knowledge in a particular topic (the tag scoring system):

[image: My tag wall of glory!]

<sub>Cupcake's tag wall of glory!</sub>

It's not *perfect*, but it's *good enough*, in my opinion.

As for "certifications", again, there are already tag badges that are given to users who acquire a certain number of upvotes for answering a certain number of questions in a topic:

[image: Cupcake's gold tag badge of glory!]

### Filtering Questions

Again, there are systems already in place to filter questions by topic and difficulty. Tags can be used to filter questions by topic, and the question scoring system can be used as a rough measure of difficulty:

- Some highly-voted questions with low views have a chance to be "difficult".
- Some positive but low-scored questions with low views also have a chance to be "difficult".

### Reviewing Poor Answers

Once again, mechanisms are already in place to support this. This is what downvotes are for. Downvotes not only make a user lose rep, but they also make users lose points in the tag for which they answered.